# BackgroundWorker RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Cancelled always false

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, events, backgroundworker

I cancel my operation by calling the `CancelAsync()` method on the BackgroundWorker, and when execution falls into the event `RunWorkerCompleted`, property `Cancelled` on `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs` is false.

Though, I couldn't quite figure out when or where I should set it to `true`, as found in the `EventArgs` property. So, how?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx):

> The Cancelled property of
> RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs
> indicates whether a cancellation
> request was processed by the
> background operation.
>
> If your code in
> the DoWork event handler detects a
> cancellation request by checking the
> CancellationPending flag and setting
> the Cancel flag of
> DoWorkEventArgs
> to true, the Cancelled flag of
> RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs
> also will be set to true.

Comment: Now I just feel silly. I DID read MSDN's topic on the BackgroundWoker. But perhaps I didn't read RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs' topic. Anyway, thanks a lot for the quick clear answer.